# How to customize the Assertion/SoftAssert class in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

I have a scenario where I need to expand available functionalities like below:

```
    assertTrue(boolean condition, String customMessage); 
    assertEquals(String expected,String actual, String customMessage, long  startTime, long endTime);
```

Its just a purpose of creating a wrapper class file for TestNG and do some customization.